# Need help: input int from console and pass it into method in different class and do math

Tags: java

i'm a beginner, Need help, Please!!!

I want to read optional number "a" from console and then store it in variable to use as passing to a different class (different .java file). and pint the sum separetely by optional inputting.

How do i code the 2 classes? thanks

```
/*
* DemoApp.java
*/

public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        System.out.println("Input one of the following 3 numbers: 100, 200, 300");
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        TestApplication testapp = new TestApplication();
        testapp.test(a);

    }
}


/*
 * TestApplication.java
 *
 */

public class TestApplication {

    private int a; 

    public void test(int a) {
        this.a = a; // TODO: where to get the "a"? (entered by users from console)

        System.out.println("The number_a was passed in: "+a);
    }

    protected void printNum() throws Exception {

        int num;


        switch (a) {
        case 100:
            num = num + 10;
            break;

        case 200:
            num = num + 20;
            break;

        case 300:
            num = num + 30;
            break;

        default:
            // TODO: unexpected number input. throw();
            break;

        }

                System.out.println("I got a sum number"+num);

    }

}
```

---

i just wanted to keep my question simple for the demo code. hehe :)

the secenio is that i want to input 3 number separetely from console, pass it to the second class B, in the the second class B, I need to build a fully-qualified message following the protocol (one of the 3 number will be needed), and then send the message to RS-232 port. all the encoding/decoding and send/ack job is done by the third class C.
btw, the second class B is derived from the third class C.

in the demo code, it seems like the "a" is not passed into the printNum() method.

any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: More specific question, maybe?  The way you pass in 'int a' is fine, though you could use it directly instead of having a class-level 'private int a'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine... Are you wondering how to compile Java programs with two source files like this? Try...

```
javac DemoApp.java TestApplication.java
java DemoApp
```

and it should work. Unless you're using an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, in which case they should handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  The one thing I don't see is a call to your `printNum` method.  You could put a call to that in your `test(int)` method, so it would look like this:

```
 public void test(int a) {
    this.a = a; // TODO: where to get the "a"? (entered by users from console)
    System.out.println("The number_a was passed in: "+a);
    printNum();
 }
```

A couple points on `printNum`:

- there is no place in the method that will `throw` a checked `Exception`, so you should remove `throws Exception` from the signature.
- you perform math on the `num` var as if it would be modified many times, but each case of the `switch` breaks and there is no loop in the method, so there should be no `+=` required (this really shouldnt compile, as `num` will not have been initialized be the time it is dereferenced).